# Docusign: how to change the <name> via docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I need help on how to change the names that appear when sending an email to a recipient thru DocuSign.    I am using REST API and I copied one of the examples DocuSign have.  I can change the email subject but I don't know how top change the [name] in the email body.  Below is an example on how to change the email subject.  I'm using c# Web Development.

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.EmailSubject = "Please read, review and sign the retail contract document";
```

These are the ones I want to change, anything with [name]:

1. [name] via docusign <-- it appears on the email From
2. [name] sent you a document to review and sign  <-- appears inside a blue box inside under the email Body.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sender/Signer names are automatically merged into the emails by the default email formats.

They can however, be changed with the Email Resource File in the branding section (Classic UI). Specific documentation on the default formats, and modifying them can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-email-resource-file(v1.1).pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your response.   I tried to do that already.  I went to the branding section, under email resources I hit download master then after I got the file, I changed the [[senderName]] to for example my name then tried to upload back to resource and error comes up.  It says "Account activation failed (you need to take action).  This is in the demo account.

Comment: Also is it possible to change it in the API? the [senderName] can be Dealer A, B or C.  It is a variable.